# Does price of american (put) option exhibit smooth pasting in time direction under B-S model?

Tags: black-scholes, american-options

Let us consider the BS model and let $f(s,t)$ denote the price of an American put option with $t$ to expiry, then it is known the solution of the optimal stopping  (when it is risk neutral) related to this American put option can be characterised by a curve continuous, monotonically decreasing, convex curve $c(t)$ such that $c(0)=K$ and $c(\infty)$ is a known limit from the perpetual problem.

Let us denote $C$ as the continuation region of this problem, that is $\{(s,t):s>C(t)\}$ and $D=C^c$ is the stopping region. It is well established that smooth pasting is exhibited at the boundary, that is to say

$$\lim_{(t,s)\rightarrow(T,C(T))}\partial_sf(s,t)= -1$$

This condition can be proved in many different ways via classical theory as well as arguments using viscosity solutions. My question is that: is anything known about time derivative when we approach the boundary?

For example, does

$$\lim_{(t,s)\rightarrow(T,C(T))}\partial_tf(s,t)= 0$$

hold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Black-Scholes PDE holds in the continuation region : 
$$ u_t = - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 u_{ss} $$ (ignoring interest rate).  This says that theta is as smooth as gamma.  The "smooth pasting" literature you mention shows that delta is continuous at the exercise boundary, but gamma has a jump.  So theta has a jump as well.  In other words, in the time direction price is continuous but its derivative is not.

Comment: I do not quite understand why you can ignore the other terms. if you have 0 interest rate, an american put is a European put (by convexity of the pay off) then your continution is everywhere and this problem is meaningless.

Comment: Anyhow, i see your point, i think it is valid if you put the other terms back - do you know any source which says the second derivative is not continous? (I know this is true for a perpetual option as explicit expression exists, but seen nothing explicit written in the finite horizon put option case)